# Fourier series representing a continuous function?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am fairly sure the answer to my question is "No", so this is more of an affirmation/reference request question.

Given a Fourier series $\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} a_k e^{kxi}$, we can view it as an $L^2$-function on $S^1$. My question is: Given the Fourier coefficients $a_k$, can we decide whether this function is actually continuous? This is so if the $a_k$ are $L^1$-summable, but this is not an "if and only if"-condition. Is there an "if and only if"-condition?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, in the world of Fourier transforms, the Fourier transform (i.e, coefficient) does indicate whether the function is continuous.  Specifically, if the Fourier transform

$$\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \, e^{i k x}$$

behaves as $1/k^{m+1}$ for some integer $m$ as $k \to \infty$, then $f(x)$ has a discontinuity in its $m$th derivative.  For example, for $\hat{f}(k) = \sin{\pi k}/(\pi k)$, then $f(x)$ has a discontinuity at $x=\pm 1$ ($m=1$).  For $\hat{f}(k) = \sin^2{\pi k}/(\pi k)^2$, then $f'(x)$ has a discontinuity at $x=\pm 2$ and at $x=0$.  And so on.

I suspect this translates to Fourier coefficients (i.e,, periodic functions), but I cannot prove it definitively.

Comment: The rates of decay of $\hat{f}$ corresponds to smoothness of $f$. This is true for Fourier series also. But this is weaker than OP's $l^1$ assumption (faster than $\frac{1}{m^{k+\epsilon}}$ decay implies $l^1$) and doesn't quite address the question.

Comment: @Michael: "My question is: Given the Fourier coefficients $a_k$, can we decide whether this function is actually continuous?"  While I admit that my observation may or may not be spot-on, I do not see how on earth it doesn't address that question.

Comment: Like OP already said, $l^1$ implies continuity. The conditions you quote are stronger than $l^1$ and implies (the stronger conclusion of) smoothness, as they should. But this doesn't say anything about the more general question of continuity.